# Loop over a range of IPs with perl IP library

Tags: perl, ipv4

I'm trying to create an IP table list where I can see which IPs are in use and which aren't.

I use the `Net::IP` library for this. Code snippet:

```
my @IPsinrange = &getAllIPs($range) ; #range is x.x.x.x/subnet format
sub getAllIPs {
    my $ip = new Net::IP ($range) || die;
    my @IPs ;
    # Loop
    do {
        push @IPs, $ip->ip() ;
    } while (++$ip);

    return @IPs ;   
}
```

This works for a x.x.x.0/24 network and this works for 1.2.3.4/32 but when I use 1.2.3.4/29 for instance, the loop just dies. I thought it could be because of the fact that there were no IP adresses in use, but there are 4 IPs in that range that are alive.

Comment: You should use `my $ip = Net::IP->new($range) or die` instead of `my $ip = new Net::IP ($range) || die;`. The indirect object notation is old and discouraged, and the `||` is very sticky on the left.

Comment: Also, do `die $!` to see _why_ it dies.

Comment: `1.2.3.4/29` is not a valid IP range. The `.4` falls smack dab in the middle of a `/29` prefix. `1.2.3.0/29` would be the valid "range".

Comment: @simbabque unfortunately, this module just uses `die;`. It does not return or display any information whatsoever as to why it died.

Comment: @stevieb shouldn't I get an .1 through .6 IP list then or do I misunderstand the module?

Comment: @stevieb, If you read the fine manual, http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm, you'll see that proper usage is `my $ip = new Net::IP ('193.0.1/24') or die (Net::IP::Error());` which does, in fact, return the exact reason the constructor failed.

Comment: @PaulL thanks for that.

Comment: you'll get 0-7 if you supply a correct /29 IP range: `$range = 1.2.3.0/29;` However, of course, 0 and 7 are not usable IPs in this case, 1-6 are. 0 is the network address, and 7 is the broadcast address

Comment: @stevieb: yes, that did the trick! If you could post this as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it

Comment: posted answer as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is due to the fact that the module requires you to send in a proper network address as the starting point of a given IP prefix.

Since you want to use a `/29` prefix, valid ranges would be:

```
1.2.3.0/29
1.2.3.8/29
1.2.3.16/29
...etc
```

As mentioned in the comments, the documentation states that the proper usage of the constructor to get proper diagnostic output is:

```
$ip = Net::IP->new('1.2.3.0/29') or die (Net::IP::Error());
```

Comment: I just changed your answer to use direct object notation. Feel free to rollback my edit if you don't like that.

Comment: @PerlDog nah I'm going to leave it, I considered doing that (I was testing with direct notation), but went with what the docs stated pretty much verbatim. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the [`Net::CIDR`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CIDR) function library instead. The function `Net::CIDR::cidr2octets` does exactly what you need, and doesn't insist that the base address for a range is the network address

Here's an example that uses your test data `1.2.3.4/29` for the range

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Net::CIDR;

my @range = Net::CIDR::cidr2octets('1.2.3.4/29');

say for @range;
```

#### output

```
1.2.3.0
1.2.3.1
1.2.3.2
1.2.3.3
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.5
1.2.3.6
1.2.3.7
```

If you want to "normalize" a CIDR block that may not use the network address as the prefix, you can use `Net::CIDR::cidr2range` followed by `Net::CIDR::range2cidr`. Given `'1.2.3.4/29'`, the first returns `1.2.3.0-1.2.3.7`, and when that result is passed into `Net::CIDR::range2cidr` we get a normalised result

Like so

```perl
Net::CIDR::range2cidr(Net::CIDR::cidr2range('1.2.3.4/29'));
```

#### output

```
1.2.3.0/29
```

Comment: Looks promising! The only weird thing I get is that a /24 doesn't give an output of .0 - .255 but just 1.2.3. Other subnet masks look okay